# ConstraintLayout's Placeholder with wrap_content width/height with an odd behaviour

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When using the `ConstraintLayout`'s `Placeholder` with `wrap_content` width and height, if a content is set to the placeholder itself, it occupies the correct space on screen, as the example below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#990000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/action_placeholder_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Placeholder
        android:id="@+id/action_placeholder_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:content="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout output of when the content is set]

---

But, when no content is set to it, it occupies a bunch of space (the entire area) instead of having 0dp width/height. The example below demonstrates that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#990000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/action_placeholder_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Placeholder
        android:id="@+id/action_placeholder_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout output of when the content is not set]

---

Is that some kind of `ConstraintLayout` bug or am I doing something wrong?

Context: I want to set the content of the placeholder only when the page is fully loaded.

---

The `ConstraintLayout` version I am using is:

> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:**1.1.3**'

Comment: I don't think this -as written- has enough constraints to determine where to position and measure all the things, and as such, it may be failing to measure and position the views when the button is missing. What are you exactly trying to accomplish here? At the very least, you need a Horizontal Chain or some sort of constraint for your placeholder to know where it should go in relation to the View_1.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @MartinMarconcini. I did not know about the attribute. But unfortunately it had no effect. Using both possible values, the `Placeholder` is still occupying the entire area :/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, I want to leave the `Placeholder` with no content (empty) until my page is fully loaded.

Comment: Interesting usage of the word "page" here. My question is, what do you need the placeholder for? Or are you using a placeholder because you found it elsewhere?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, I am using the `Placeholder` to set the correct position that some views have to take, depending on the Page state. It's content may be a `Switch`, `Button` or any other `View` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a proper horizontal chain so `ConstraintLayout` knows where `view_1` is supposed to align in case view it's constrainted to is gone. Your placeholder should have `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view_1"`.

You can also consider adding `app:emptyVisibility="invisible"` (or `visible`) and see how it affects the layout.

Comment: Hi, @Pawel :). Thanks for the reply \o/. I have just tested to use the attribute `app:emptyVisibility` with the following values: `invisible` and `gone` (all the values possible), but it is still not working =/. Could you please post an example in xml, please? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a Placeholder (and I honestly don't know why it's behaving this way for I've never used them), but that's because I've never needed them to begin with.

This is how I'd do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#999999">

    <View
            android:id="@+id/view_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#990000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If the button is VISIBLE (as ^), it would look like:
[image: Visible]

If the button is GONE, it would look like:
[image: Gone]

And if the button is INVISIBLE, it would reserve the space and look like:
[image: Invisible]

Start with the Gone or Invisible (depending upon what you want your UI/UX to look like in that state), and once you're "done loading your page", then push a new view state (which will result in the button becoming Visible).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @MarginMarconcini. But that example doesn't use a `Placeholder` :/

Comment: I don't think you need a Placeholder; in fact, I'd go ahead and say that Placeholders are a mistake in ConstraintLayout; even the Google Engineers said (and I [quote](https://academy.realm.io/posts/360-andev-2017-nicolas-roard-advanced-constraintlayout/)): "I think the jury is still out on this one if it's that useful or not." They are an interesting concept, but probably not needed if you maintain the view state separated and inflate what you need, when you need.

Comment: In my opinion, its concept is actually interesting. Placeholders can be used to determine a location on a layout where, in that location, you may set two or more different views, depending on the "Page State". Using Placeholders saves you from setting the same position configuration for multiple other views. It's easier to change only one View's position configuration than two or more.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, beyond what I've given. I think `Placeholders` are a mistake, they don't function the way you think they do, simply because of the nature of how ConstraintLayout (and AutoLayout on iOS) work; the measure/layout pass(es) cannot magically infer what you're going to place, and as such, the widget must respond "something" so the entire layout can be placed. This problem has been already "resolved" by using ViewModels and if "changing 2 or more" views is difficult for you, then look at DataBinding, or simply transition to a new view state...

Comment: My conclusion is that you're trying to solve a problem in the wrong "layer". But I don't have your project in front of me, and I am not working with you on this, so, I may be totally wrong. This sounds like a concept coming from web development, which is usually not how it translates when it comes to native Android (or to a similar extent, iOS).

Comment: Alrighty. Thanks for all the time you invested on trying to help me, @MartinMarconcini. I'm grateful for it :).

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with this. Hopefully some Google engineer can give you a better answer. o/